# If I created a SQL Server database in C#, where can I check it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms

I am going to create a database with SQL Server in C#, and also make basic queries.

And I wrote the following code to create the database.

Where can I find my database?

I downloaded SSMS but I am not sure how to check it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MakeBusDB
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string query;
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");
            query = "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS Session1DB";
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                query = "CREATE DATABASE Session1DB";
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzImc.png)

Comment: Open SSMS, connect to your local instance, view the databases...

Comment: OK yes, but what is stopping you from doing that? Have you opened SSMS yet?

Comment: I opend it. But there isn't existing my database.

Comment: Screenshot, please? :)

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? The IF EXISTS option is only available from SQL Server 2016 (13.x).

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you will need to assign that string containing your <create database> statement to your command before you execute it the second time.

Comment: wow, maybe this is correct answer! Thanks. I'll try this